# Retrieving Github secrets with spaces from golang script

Tags: go, github-actions-runners

I would like to retrieve a Github secret content from a script via Golang, that is executed from Github actions.
In this particular situation, the secret value stored in Github secrets has a space. I mean the secret value is: `JWT <token-string>`.

The way to retrieve Github secrets from any script in any language as long they are executed in Github actions runners is by reading them as environment variables. So what I am doing is to read it in this way: (Please see the `Authorization:` element in the slice of string below)

```
func MyTestFunction(t *testing.T, serverURL string) {

    type AppLogin struct {
        token string
    }
    method := "GET"

    
    headers := map[string][]string{
        "Content-Type": []string{"application/json, text/plain, */*"},
        "Authorization": []string{os.Getenv("USER_JWT")},
    }
```

The thing is that I am not getting the value from Github secrets when running Github action runner. I know this is happening since I tried to print it in this way, but nothing comes up:

```
fmt.Println("My JWT", os.Getenv("USER_JWT"))
```

I am afraid it is happening because that space between `"JWT "` and the token, I mean `JWT <token-string>`.

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#naming-your-secrets) says:

> Secret names can only contain alphanumeric characters ([a-z], [A-Z], [0-9]) or underscores (_). **Spaces are not allowed.**

As an important fact, my token secret value also contains `.` character in its value. The value is something like this:

```
JWT xxxxxxx8888xxxxdsdsfsfsf9.eyJxxxxxxx8888xxxxdsdsfsfsf9.Tfgxadsdsfsfsasasad_s7sdsdsfgsgcs
```

So I believe, that is the reason why I cannot get the secret value.

I am not sure how I can fetch this from my Golang script, I even tried to modify the Github secret value just having it as a value the `<token-string>` in order to avoid the space in the value, and I am calling it from go in this way:

```
"Authorization": []string{"JWT ", os.Getenv("SPECKLE_USER_JWT")}
```

But it did not work.
I read [here](https://github.community/t/secret-with-special-escape-characters-fails-when-used/17108/3?u=bgarcial) that when calling secrets with special characters from github actions we have to escape them with single quotes `' '` but this process is from `.yaml` file github actions.

The previous solution alternatives I am trying to, they works on my local machine, since my bash cli is able to get environment variables with spaces in their values. I am not sure how can I - let's say "escape" - a secret with space in a string as I have from golang.

Comment: can you show the workflow yaml as well?

Comment: @WishwaPerera, since the go code is a test, from GitHub actions YAML file I am just executing the `go test` command to initiate the process.

Comment: @WishwaPerera your hint was right, I was missing to involve calling the secret variable on my github action yaml file. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to read the JWT secret stored in GitHub secrets from a GitHub action executing the golang terratest code.

As mentioned, since Github secrets does not allow spaces `" "` and dots `.`  characters and the token has some dots plus one space, that I did first was to encode it

```
echo -n '<token-value>' | base64
```

This generates a whole string without `.` or spaces and then I stored this value on Github secrets. And I read it from golang in this way:

```
func main() {
   var t *testing.T
   serverURL := os.Getenv("SERVER_URL")
   MyTestFunction(t, serverURL)

}
func MyTestFunction(t *testing.T, serverURL string) {

    type SpeckleLogin struct {
        token string
    }
    method := "GET"

    // The encoded token is read from github secrets
    b64EncodeJwt := os.Getenv("USER_JWT_ENCODE")
    // fmt.Println("The encode JWT is:", b64EncodeJwt)

    // The encoded read token is decoded
    b64DecodeJwt, _ := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(b64EncodeJwt)
    // fmt.Println("JWT Decoded", string(b64DecodeJwt))
    // fmt.Println()
    
    headers := map[string][]string{
        "Content-Type": []string{"application/json, text/plain, */*"},
        
        // The content of the token already decoded is included in the headers slice of strings. 
        "Authorization": []string{(string(b64DecodeJwt))},
    }


    jsonLogin := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{
        "email":"%s",
        "password": "%s"
    }`, os.Getenv("USER_EMAIL"), os.Getenv("USER_PASSWORD")))
    
    // The HTTP request is created
    reqLogin, errReq := http.NewRequest(method, serverURL+"/api/accounts", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonLogin))

    // The headers are added to the HTTP request
    reqLogin.Header = headers

    if errReq != nil {
        messageReq := fmt.Sprintf("Error GET login request: %s", errReq.Error())
        t.Fatal(messageReq)
    }

    clientLogin := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
            },
        },
    }
    // Sending the request
    respLogin, errResp := clientLogin.Do(reqLogin)

    if errResp != nil {
        messageResp := fmt.Sprintf("Error GET login response: %s", errResp.Error())
        t.Fatal(messageResp)
    }

    defer respLogin.Body.Close()

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(respLogin.Body)

    // fmt.Println("BODY IS:")
    // fmt.Println(string(body))

    var speckleLogin map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &speckleLogin); err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Could not unmarshal json")
    }

    // We take the API token from the response
    data := speckleLogin["resource"].(map[string]interface{})["apitoken"]   

    if speckleToken, ok := data.(string); ok {

        // Here we assert the token is not empty
        assert.NotEmpty(t, speckleToken)
}
```

But in addition as [@WishwaPerera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15968273/wishwa-perera) try to tell me, the new environment variable i am using from golang called `SPECKLE_USER_JWT_ENCODE` above, has to be included in my github actions at the moment to run these tests from `go test` command. So my github action `.yaml` file finally is in this way:

```
name: Preview_Workflow

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Install terraform 
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        terraform_version: 0.13.5
        terraform_wrapper: false

    - name: 'Terraform Version'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        terraform version

    - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: 'Setup Go'
      id: go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: '^1.16.5'

    - name: 'Run Terratest'
      id: terratest
      run: |
        cd tests
        go get -u github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob
        go get -u github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform
        go get -u github.com/stretchr/testify/assert
        // executing the test
        go test
      env:
        SERVER_URL: "https://my-service-application-url"
        USER_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.USER_EMAIL }}
        USER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.USER_PASSWORD }}
        USER_JWT_ENCODE: ${{ secrets.USER_JWT_ENCODE }}

        # I am using these other ones to connect to azure.
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
        ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}

    - name: Azure logout
      run: |
        az logout
```

A nice reference to understand a bit [how to handle the HTTP package](https://practical-go-lessons.com/chap-35-build-an-http-client)